# Activities and Nodes in One Calendar

Tags: drupal-views, calendar

I currently use Drupal's Calendar module to display CiviCRM activities on a Views Calendar. I also have another content type that displays nodes on a Views Calendar. Is it possible to display both CiviCRM activites and content type nodes in one calendar?

I tried the CiviCRM Entity module, but activities don't seem to be available as a field.

Comment: Which version of the CiviCRM entity module did you try? Going off the cuff, but I think the 2.0 dev branch does have them as entities.

Comment: I tried both the stable and dev version and it isn't currently available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal Views starts off with a base table - do you want to look at:  User, Nodes, CiviCRM activities and so on.

So if the base table is Nodes, then it's looking at nodes for the date info and displaying them.

If the base table is CiviCRM Activities, it's looking at those for the date info and displaying them.

But currently in Views you cannot combine this data. They are two separate views.

Back in the forums there has always been discussions about combining Drupal node dates and CiviCRM event dates - it's the same problem.

So out of the box there is not really a solution for this.